# No attribute CV_CAP_OPENNI

Tags: python, opencv, kinect, openni

While running a simple code on Open CV:

```
import cv2

import freenect

device = cv2.CV_CAP_OPENNI

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(device)
```

While running the above python code.I am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "hello.py", line 4, in <module>
device = cv2.CV_CAP_OPENNI
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CV_CAP_OPENNI'
```

Please look into the code

I have already installed OPENNI.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `cv2.CAP_OPENNI` instead of `cv2.CV_CAP_OPENNI`

Answer (score 0):

To make it work properly, the installation should be proper and the method is as follows:

Make is using the proper repository. The link to the repository is:
https://github.com/jmendeth/PyOpenNI

**You can directly use the code below to download and make**

git clone https://github.com/jmendeth/PyOpenNI.git
mkdir PyOpenNI-build
cd PyOpenNI-build
cmake ../PyOpenNI

After installing, dont use "make install", instead copy the lib/openni.so found in the folder you have installed(PyOpenNI-build if you have used the above code to install).

Finally copy it your python install folder. In my case "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages".

**Testing**

Test using the following python code:

import openni

Now the above code will also start running.